# How to sort an array according to the datetime in 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss' format in the descending order?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, datetime

For example, the datetime format is like this:
"03-11-2018 06:48:23"
How can I sort an array containing datetime of this type?

I tried something like this

```
this.fetchedData.sort(function compare(a, b) {
        var dateA = +new Date(a.date);
        var dateB = +new Date(b.date);
        return dateB - dateA;
      });
```

The JSON array is:

```
this.fetchedData = [ {chat_id: "60",
                      date: "03-11-2018 06:48:23",
                      firstname: "0",
                      img: "1541223654.png",
                      lastname: "test",
                      message: "jhsjaddhsad",
                      thread_id: "0048211296764753"
                      },

                      {chat_id: "61",
                      date: "03-12-2018 07:50:20",
                      firstname: "1",
                      img: "1541245654.png",
                      lastname: "test",
                      message: "dhsad",
                      thread_id: "0048218896764753"
                      } ];
```

But this code is not working for me.

Comment: What do you mean? Please post your attempts at solving this problem, and the array, and also the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the format is in 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss', new Date(date) will throw invalid date error. For Ex: new Date('23-11-2018 06:48:23')

The logic you are having is correct, but new Date() won't work with all date formats.

Use following:

```
var pattern = /(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
this.fetchedData.sort(function compare(a, b) {
    var dateA = +new Date(a.date.replace(pattern,'$3-$2-$1T$4:$5:$6'));
    var dateB = +new Date(b.date.replace(pattern,'$3-$2-$1T$4:$5:$6'));
    return dateB - dateA;
});
```

**Or**

you can use **Moment** library or any other appropriate library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date()` for each array values and compare that for sorting in descending order:

```js
var fetchedData = [{
    chat_id: "60",
    date: "03-11-2018 06:48:23",
    firstname: "0",
    img: "1541223654.png",
    lastname: "test",
    message: "jhsjaddhsad",
    thread_id: "0048211296764753"
  },
  {
    chat_id: "61",
    date: "03-12-2018 07:50:20",
    firstname: "1",
    img: "1541245654.png",
    lastname: "test",
    message: "dhsad",
    thread_id: "0048218896764753"
  },
  {
    chat_id: "61",
    date: "03-09-2018 07:50:20",
    firstname: "1",
    img: "1541245654.png",
    lastname: "test",
    message: "dhsad",
    thread_id: "0048218896764753"
  }
];

fetchedData.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));

console.log(fetchedData);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer. My guess is that it was downvoted for appearing to be a duplicate of previous incorrect but similar answers. The thing to note here is that this string is the [ISO 8601 extended format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), which is officially supported by the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor, and not a non-standard format that would otherwise result in inconsistent behavior across browsers.

Comment: Well, actually now that I'm looking closely, you have a space instead of a `T`. Change that or you _will_ be causing inconsistent behavior with this answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts OP has changed the data structure and I have answered based on that.

Comment: My comment still stands. You're relying on implementation-specific behavior. Browsers are not required by the specification to initialize correct dates from these non-standard strings.